# SharePoint 2010 site collection quota

Tags: storage

In SharePoint 2007, there was a useful tool underneath Site Collection Administration called “Storage space allocation” that led to storman.aspx underneath http://servername/_layouts/storman.aspx.

This storman tool allowed you to view how your space was being used within your site collection, and if you were filling up your site against your storage quota, you could show documents, document libraries, lists, and recycle bins, sorted by size or date.  This was a great way to find large or old documents to delete and free up space.

Unfortunately, this tool is not available with SharePoint 2010.  How can a site collection administrator that is approaching their storage quota find out what is using up their space (whether larger or old content is the culprit)?

Comment: Has the site had a new quota applied to it since the migration?  I didn't think storman was depricated in 2010.  THat sucks if it did :-(

Comment: Yeah, storman was depracated :)

Comment: It is making it's triumphant return in Service Pack 1, horray!

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to see what is taking up space is to use SharePoint Designer. When you click on items in the Navigation Panel, the gallery shows the items and the space that is used by each.

Comment: Neat trick.  I see it shows me the site collection quota, but it doesn't seem to show the size of subsites or lists.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: if you can see the file structure of the site, you should be able to click on that and see sizes in teh gallery, you can expand lists and libraries there as well. and even see individual item sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Site Collection Web Analytics provides a report called Storage Usage at: _layouts/WebAnalytics/Report.aspx?t=StorageTrendsReport&l=sc

It shows the trend in storage growth for the entire site collection against the quota, but doesn't drill down to lower levels.

Answer (score 1):

Service Pack 1 for Sharepoint 2010 is bringing back "StorMan", [link](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?pID=973).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach (creating a visual view of everything in your Site Collection using WinDirStat) here.  It will hammer your WFE's with WebDAV as it enumerates the content of your site collection, but may be a workable solution if you do it during off-hours:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2010/09/29/sharepoint-2010-storman-on-steroids.aspx